# How to organize xml elements of same level into different hierarchy

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this element

```
<products>
<item>
 <abc>2</abc>
 <def>m</def>
 <gih>C</gih>
</item>
<item>
 <abc>2</abc>
 <def>m</def>
 <gih>A</gih>
</item>
<item>
 <abc>2</abc>
 <def>m</def>
 <gih>A</gih>
</item>
<item>
 <abc>2</abc>
 <def>m</def>
 <gih>C</gih>
</item>
<item>
 <abc>2</abc>
 <def>m</def>
 <gih>A</gih>
</item>
</products>
```

This has to be converted to

```
<products>
<message>
 <item>
  <abc>2</abc>
  <def>m</def>
  <gih>C</gih>
 </item>
 <item>
  <abc>2</abc>
  <def>m</def>
  <gih>A</gih>
 </item>
<item>
 <abc>2</abc>
 <def>m</def>
 <gih>A</gih>
 </item>
</message>
<message>
 <item>
  <abc>2</abc>
  <def>m</def>
  <gih>C</gih>
</item>
<item>
 <abc>2</abc>
 <def>m</def>
 <gih>A</gih>
</item>
</message>
</products>
```

Actually whenever element gih has a value C new message has to be made. The xml is always sorted starting with C and then As.

A in gih element means that the item has to be appended.

Can anyone suggest an xslt? much appreciated!

Comment: This is a grouping problem. Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to do in XSLT 2.0 - less so in XSLT 1.0:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-starting-with="item[gih='C']">
            <message>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
            </message>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="item-by-leader" match="item[not(gih='C')]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::item[gih='C'][1])" />

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="item[gih='C']">
            <message>
                <xsl:copy-of select=". | key('item-by-leader', generate-id())" />
            </message>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Michael, hats off! Thanks a billion!